# How to get perf annotate to display source when the binary is not compiled with -g?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

We're doing perf record on our release binary and then we do perf annotate to drill down into hotspots. But since we don't compile release binaries with -g, perf annotate only shows disassembly.

Is there someway we can
1) compile two versions of the application - one with symbols and one without.
2) do perf record on the version without symbols
3) do perf annotate on the version with symbols to see perf events attributed to source code line

Comment: You can compile application with debug info and then strip this debug info (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html). But instead of deleting debug info you can use objcopy to put it into separate file. Then you can profile the stripped binary with perf, and reuse this debuginfo (not sure about exact commands). There is some info in [BPF book by Gregg](www.brendangregg.com/bpf-performance-tools-book.html) with `eu-unstrip`:  https://books.google.com/books?id=ihTADwAAQBAJ&pg=PT723&lpg=PT723&dq=perf+debuginfo+objcopy& or https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Jolsa_Docs_Annotations